# Change separator of attributions in Leaflet?

Tags: leaflet, qgis2web

Is there a way to change the comma shown in the image below to |

[image: The attribution section of a Leaflet map]

I used the QGIS plugin QGIS2WEb to create the Leaflet map and wanted to link to the source of the information.

Currently, in the HTML code I have used the attribution format like so:

```
var overlay_GoogleHybrid_0 = L.tileLayer('https://mt1.google.com/vt/lyrs=y&x={x}&y={y}&z={z}', {
        opacity: 1.0,
        attribution:'<a href="https://google.com" target="_blank">Base Layer Map info &copy; Google</a>',
    });
```

I am also unsure if this is the correct method of referencing the Google Hybrid layer I am using (Obtained using the Quick Map Services plugin).

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The short answer is no, because that comma is generated by Leaflet itself:

```
prefixAndAttribs.push(attribs.join(', '));
```

https://github.com/Leaflet/Leaflet/blob/master/src/control/Control.Attribution.js#L103

The long answer is that, with work, the "qgis2web" part could be moved into the attribution's prefix (ie before the pipe symbol) - in fact that would be quite a good idea, but requires development of the qgis2web plugin itself. Individual layer attributions would still be comma-separated, though.

Comment: Ok thanks for the quick reply, would be a decent addition as it looks a bit odd without it.

Comment: I've made this change to qgis2web master branch. It will be part of the next release of the plugin.